# Problems installing Thinkphp with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

After I run this command:

```
composer create-project topthink/think o2o
```

The remote server throws this warning and error:

> `The directory has contained a file composer.json`

Why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the message:

> Could not decompress the archive **enable the PHP zip extension**

You have to enable the php-zip extension. To do this, use:

PHP5:

```
php5enmod zip
```

PHP7:

```
phpenmod zip
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem by using command : apt-get install php7.0-zip